# can't catch an exception when string does not exist in "database"

Tags: java

I have something like this:

```
...
while (itr.hasNext()) {
...
try {

    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(theData.getName())
        || (country.getName().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase(theData.getName()))
       {

        result = new Country(PointT, dist);
        break;

      } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < repl.size(); i++) { 

          if (repl.get(i).toString().contains(theData.getName())) {

            theName = true;
            result = new Country(PointTt, dist, theName);
            break;
          } else if (theParts.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(theData.getName())) {
            result = new Country(PointT, dist);
            break;
          } 
        } 


      }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
      logger.error("Does not exist in database", ex);
      throw ex;
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {

      logger.error("Does not exist in database", ex);
      throw ex;
    }catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error("Does not exist in database", ex);
      throw ex;
    }
}
...
```

So, I am comparing with `theData.getName()`,  the `userInput` which is just a String, `country.getName()` which is also a String, `repl.get(i)` which is a `List<String>` , `theParts.get(i)` which is also a `List<String>`.

I can't find a solution to make this work.To throw an exception when the string does not exist in database `(theData.getName())`.

## Read data

In order to read `theData`:

I am using `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filelocation);`

Then, extract only the Strings and store them:

`ArrayList<String> theNames = new ArrayList<String>();`

and then I merge `theNames` together with other iterators and create

`ArrayList<theNamesLoc> theNamesLocList = new ArrayList<theNamesLoc>();`

and that is the array list where I apply :

```
Iterator<TheNamesLoc> itr = theNamesLocList.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {

..}
```

Comment: if ( !next() ) throw .. ? something like that? you don't show how you read your data, so how are we supposed to know?

Comment: is theData null? Are you checking it first before using it?

Comment: How about `if(theData == null) throw xyzException`?

Comment: @Stultuske:I updated code.

Comment: @Assafs:Yes, I am checking.The data is not null.I just wan to know if user input lies in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

assuming repl is the list in which all responses from the database are saved, there can be two cases:

1. Given input is a part of any string in the list (Ex: input is 'xyz' and list contains an element 'axyzw').
2. Input matches entirely with one of the items in the list.

First Case:

```
boolean isPresent = false;
for(String elem: list){
    if(elem.contains("xyz")){//check each string if it contains the element
        isPresent = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!isPresent){
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Element wasn't found in the list");
}
```

Second Case:

Second case is pretty simple:

```
if(!list.contains("xyz")){
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found");
}
```

Ultimately, you'll have to "throw" the exception which can later be catched wherever required.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

If I got your question right, You need to define an else block and "Throw" the exception.

```
if (repl.get(i).toString().contains(theData.getName())) {
....
} else{
    throw new NoSuchElementException(args...);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I implement something like this , when I have if-else-for-if statements?

Comment: I used a combination of a boolean flag and try catch.Thanks